# ReCaptcha MVC razor Validation Message not getting triggered

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax, umbraco, recaptcha

I am fairly new to MVC and a little stumped on this one.

I implemented ReCaptcha last night in my Umbraco MVC 4 application (6.1.6).
ReCaptcha works, the controller gets the correct captcha valid state and all is good.  The problem is when the captcha is incorrect, I set the ModelState.AddModelError(string, string) and return the model in order to show that the captcha entered as incorrect, but the view never triggers the Html.ValidateMessage("captcha-error") to show the actual error message updated in the ModelState.

Any help or advice would be appreciated

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[RecaptchaControlMvc.CaptchaValidator]
public ActionResult SubmitContactFormAction(Models.ContactFormModel model, bool captchaValid, string captchaErrorMessage)
{
    if (!captchaValid)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("captcha-error", captchaErrorMessage);
        return View(model);
    }
    else
    {
        // Test ModelState and do stuff
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model WebStaging.Models.ContactFormModel
@using Recaptcha
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SubmitContactFormAction", "ContactForm", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { @id = "frmContactForm" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div>
    Fields marked with * are required<br/><br />
    <div class="clear pad-5">
        <div class="label-column">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name) * 
        </div>
        <div class="input-column">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "input-242" })<br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear pad-5">
        <div class="label-column">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email) * 
        </div>
        <div class="input-column">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "input-242" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear pad-5">
        <div class="label-column">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone) 
        </div>
        <div class="input-column">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone, new { @class = "input-242" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear pad-5">
        <div class="label-column">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subject) * 
        </div>
        <div class="input-column">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Subject, new { @class = "input-242" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear pad-5">
        <div class="label-column">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message) * 
        </div>
        <div class="input-column">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { @class = "input-textarea" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="captcha-panel" class="clear" style="text-align: right; float: right; padding-top: 5px;">
        @Html.Raw(Html.GenerateCaptcha("captcha", "white"))       
    </div>
    <p>
    <div id="captcha-result" class="clear">
        @Html.ValidationMessage("captcha-error")
    </div>
    <div class="clear pad-5" style="float: right; text-align: center;">
        <button type="submit">Send</button><br />  
        <div id="submit-status" style="color: Green;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So I changed the form from ajax to a regular posted form (Html.BeginUmbracoForm()) and it worked as expected.  So there is something I am not doing correct in my ajax / JSON.

Answer (score 2):

I think problem is caused because ReCaptcha is not a simple web control. I think you can easy walk around problem changing your "captcha-result" div with new class or style attribute.

```
 <div id="captcha-result" class="someClassWithRedBigFont" >
    @Html.ValidationMessage("captcha-error")
</div>
```

If you using jQuery you can check [jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).